# Background image in CSS auto

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a database for Background Image and Text for Title. I have also a gridview were its connected also in the database.

CODE:

```
<div id="BgImage">
<asp:Label ID="Emp_Channel" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="XX-Large"></asp:Label>
 <asp:GridView>
</div>
```

In CODE BEHIND:

```
string _bgimg = row[1].ToString();
Bgimage.Attributes.Add("Style", "background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image: url(" + _bgimg + ");");
Emp_Channel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(row[0].ToString());
grid1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(row[0].ToString());
```

CSS:

```
#Bgimage
{
 width: 1188px;
 height: 703px;
 background-size:cover;
 margin-left: 0px;
}
```

My problem here, the background image is depending on the height or data of the Gridview. I want it to be like a background image were it will fill all the browser..

Is there a way how to do it? I don't like fix width and height. I want it to be automatically fill up... I already tried the width and height will become "AUTO" and "100%" but its not working..

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML Code:
<body id="Body">
    <div id="BgImage">
        <asp:Label ID="Emp_Channel" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="XX-Large"></asp:Label>
        <asp:GridView>
    </div>
</body>

CodeBehind Code:
//Bgimage.Attributes.Add("Style", "background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image: url(" + _bgimg + ");");
Body.Attributes.Add("Style", "background-image: url(" + _bgimg + ");");

CSS Code:
body {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: its  working.. but its still depends on the height of the gridview

Comment: what happens if you add background-size: contain;

Comment: @mjroodt..just a small image.. I just put the tag in the image tag instead in the body because the image is came from the database

Comment: @user1437687... its still depends in the height of the gridview.. I already copy and paste the code you given to me..The height is only our problem as of now....

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try

```
 body{
      background: url(yourimage) fixed center center;
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      }
```

Comment: @mjroodt...not working also..the background image is came from the database that's why i do it in the codebehind to call the background image

Answer (score 0):

Try it out using the following css style.

```
#BgImage
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem...

The comment of user1437687 is correct instead i just changed the css code.

```
HTML Code:
<body id="Body">
    <div id="BgImage">
        <asp:Label ID="Emp_Channel" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="XX-Large"></asp:Label>
        <asp:GridView>
    </div>
</body>

CodeBehind Code:
//Bgimage.Attributes.Add("Style", "background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image: url(" + _bgimg + ");");
Body.Attributes.Add("Style", "background-image: url(" + _bgimg + ");");

CSS Code:
body {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Updated CSS should be:

```
body {
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```